# Multiple TabItems bound to same ViewModel are not updating the first time a tab is selected

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, tabitem

I have a tabcontrol with 3 tabs on it. Each tabitem contains a different contentcontrol, all of which are bound to the same ViewModel, and there are some items in all 3 contentcontrols that are bound to the same property.

My problem is, if I change a comboBox on the initial tab, that change is not reflected on the other tabs, they still have their SelectedItem set to the default value. This only happens the first time I switch to that tab. After I have selected a tab once, everything works as expected; changes made on one tab are reflected on the other tab.

I am trying to avoid too much code-behind, and I have searched and tried all of the solutions regarding delaying of the binding, or updating the binding when the tab is selected, but I have had no luck.

Here is my TabControl:

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10">
    <TabItem Header="Tab1" IsSelected="True">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Tab1}" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab2">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Tab2}" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab3">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Tab}" />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

And here is one of the ContentControls:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Tab3" DataType="{x:Type vm:MainViewModel}">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Flow" Style="{StaticResource tabLabel}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBox}" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource tabUnitComboBox}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataList1}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedData1}" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource tabComboBox}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataList2}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedData2}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBox}" />
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Content="m³/h" Style="{StaticResource tabUnitLabel}" Visibility="{Binding SelectedData2, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource tabComboBox}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataList3}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedData3}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBox}" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource tabUnitComboBox}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataList4}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedData4}" />
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Content="Temperature" Style="{StaticResource tabLabel}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBox}" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource tabUnitComboBox}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataList5}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedData5}" />
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The ViewModel is pretty much standard, inheriting from ObservableObject and implementing OnPropertyChanged. As I said, everything works perfectly after selecting a tab once, but I would really like to get it working from the start.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you by any chance just starting with assigning the backing field. Not firing INPC on the initial load.

Comment: I am assigning it in the ViewModel to set the default index! I knew it was going to be something simple that I was overlooking. Now I just need to find another way to set the default values. Thanks!

Comment: @Blam Thanks again for the nudge in the right direction. All I had to do was implement a null check when I assigned the backing field so that it is only set once. I was so stuck on finding some complex solution that I failed to see the simplest of answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to use that comment as and answer

Are you by any chance just starting with assigning the backing field.
Not firing INPC on the initial load.